# Will installing Windows 8.1 RTM install a beta version of IE 11?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I am considering upgrading to the recently released Windows 8.1 RTM (the final version - which has been available for some time to OEM partners and MSDN subscribers). But there's one thing I am unsure of.

According to Wikipedia, [Windows 8.1 bundles Internet Explorer 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1#Windows_8.1), however the [latest version of IE11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) is still a "Release Preview". It seems very strange to me that Microsoft would bundle non-final software into an RTM release.

I would like to upgrade to Windows 8.1 but I don't want to install beta software along with it. Will I get to choose whether or not to upgrade IE when/if I install 8.1?

Comment: Actually, the Office 2013 RT included in Surface was not RTM (later update fix that), so it won't be the first.

Comment: I don't know but I would be very surprised if they were to release 8.1 (which is supposed to be fixing shortcomings in 8) and have it introduce unfinished software raising more complaints. My two cents.

Comment: 8.1 RTM includes the latest version of IE publicly available. IE will automatically be updated to the latest when newer versions/updates are available.

Comment: Now that windows 8.1 has been released this post is not longer off topic and also not primarily opinion based as this can be easily verified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is the RTM version. Wikipedia simply hasn’t been updated yet. Remember that the Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 version are different (the latter still isn’t finished)

Comment: Ok, but it's not only Wikipedia, [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-11-release-preview) still calls it a "Release Preview" (not clear whether this is final or pre-release)

Comment: @XavierPoinas This refers to the Windows 7 version. If you browse there from Windows 8.1 you don’t get the prompt. In the KB and the download center it is indicated as final.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at IE in Server 2012 R2 RTM nothing indicates it is a beta. It says 'RTM' but also version '11.0.9600.16384' which is the same that Wikipedia claims is the '17 September 2013' preview.

I assume IE will be updated over time with the normal Windows updates.

'RTM' doesn't mean the same as it used to be anymore.

I haven't done any upgrades from 8 yet, but I don't think you can choose not to upgrade to IE11.

Comment: Thanks for the first-hand information. So it isn't clear whether it is the RTM label on 8.1 that is wrong (and the actual release will ship with a different version of IE) or whether it is the Preview label on IE that actually indicates a "final" version.